# `ufunc` composition in NumPy

Tags: python, function, numpy, composition

My code contains the following definition:

```py
skew_min = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: min(x + 1, y), nin=2, nout=1)
```

The essential point, is that it is `ufunc`, because I call `skew_min.accumulate` further. But this definition is really awful. It works slow (because of python-from-native-code calls) and produces an ill-typed result (array of pyobject instead of array of float). How I dream, there should be some FP-flavored combinators to construct `ufunc` from other `ufunc`s, something like that:

```py
skew_min = compose_1(np.minimum, subst_1(np.add, 1))
```

(where made-up functions `compose_1` and `subst_1` perform `ufunc`-tional composition and substitution, correspondingly). But I have failed to find anything resembling `compose` in NumPy docs.

So, is there a nice way to compose two `ufunc`s in order to build a new one?

Comment: Most `ufunc` are builtin and compiled.  You are lucky to have found this one that lets make a `ufunc` from a python function.

Comment: In general if the provided `numpy` building blocks are incomplete, or require some sort of iteration, the best alternative is to rewrite the problem with a compilation tool like `numba` or `cython`.

Comment: A [mcve] might help us better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use numba's `@numba.vectorize` or `@numba.guvectorize` ([numba docs](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/vectorize.html)):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numba
>>> @numba.vectorize(['f8(f8, f8)', 'i8(i8, i8)'])
... def skew_min(x: float, y: float) -> float:
...     return min(x + 1, y)
...
>>> skew_min(3, 3.5)
3.5
>>> skew_min([2, 3, 4], 3.5)
array([3. , 3.5, 3.5])
>>> skew_min.outer(np.arange(3), [1.62, 2.72, 3.14])
array([[1.  , 1.  , 1.  ],
       [1.62, 2.  , 2.  ],
       [1.62, 2.72, 3.  ]])
```

As a bonus, numba jit-compiles the function, making it generally faster than using e.g. `numpy.frompyfunc` or `numpy.vectorize`.